# How to write a Conditional Custom Query in Spring boot Crud Repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, hql

I have to fetch a record from an entity table using Repository that extends CRUDRepository conditionally based on 2 fields as follows.

There are 3 fields, say a, b, and c.

```
SELECT from EntityClass e where e.a = :a AND

(e.b = :b and e.c = :c). If no record found, then it should try below one
(OR e.b = :b and e.c = null). If no record found, then it should try below one
(OR e.b = null and e.c = :c). If no record found, then it should try below one
(OR e.b = null and e.c = null).
```

There will be one or more records for sure that matches any of the 4 conditions. But I want it one record that matches anyone condition and the order matters from first to last.

How to write a Custom query for this?

```
@Query(" ")
EntityClass findEntityForAandBandC(@Param("a") String a, @Param("b") String b, @Param("c") String c);
```

I can do this from Java code using if else and writing separate query methods. But I want to write a single query method for the above.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html)

#### EntityClassRepo

```java
public class EntityClassRepo extends extends JpaRepository<Demo, Long>, 
                                             JpaSpecificationExecutor<Demo> {
}
```

so now you can use the method

> `List< T > findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec)`

- findAll() takes in `Specificaion` class, so define a specification where you could provide the conditions dynamically

I am not sure with what query you need, but the below will give you an idea.

#### EntityClassSpecificaiton (New Class)

```java
public class EntityClassSpecification implements Specification<EntityClass> {

    private EntityClassFilter entityFilter; // This holds the value A, B & C

    // Constructor 

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Demo> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        if(/* Condition */) {
            return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("a"), entityFilter.getA());
        } else if (/* Condition */) {
            return criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("b"), entityFilter.getB()), criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("c"), entityFilter.getC()));
        } else if (/* Condition */) {
            return criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("b"), entityFilter.getB()), criteriaBuilder.isNull(root.get("c")));
        } else if (/* Condition */) {
            return criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.isNull(root.get("b")), criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("c"), entityFilter.getC()));
        } else {
            return criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.isNull(root.get("b")), criteriaBuilder.isNull(root.get("c")));
        }
    }
}
```

#### Service

```java
public class EntityService {

   @Autowire
   private EntityClassRepo entityRepo;

   public List<EntityClass> getEntityClass(String a, String b, String c) {
      return entityRepo.findAll(new EntitySpecification(new EntityFilter(a, b, c)));
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't get what should be the condtion inside these if else statements. My condition is only when there is no data found in one condition only then call the else method. Can you please write an example for condition. Thanks in advance. @Avi

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom function to your repository. And you can implement the custom queries in java code.

Example:
https://dzone.com/articles/add-custom-functionality-to-a-spring-data-reposito